# The Underlying connection was closed.An unexpected error occurred on a receive in Excel DI adf

Tags: excel, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

When I am trying to insert rows into the ADF table using Excel desktop integration this exception is coming.

I tried to insert 100 records initially those are inserted successfully.

When i tried to insert the records above 500 its failing.

Answer (score 1):

We are handling the requests here using load balancer!!

Client-Timeout parameter for the load-balancer has set to 300 ms which is 5 min ~ The time taking to insert ~500 records

Once its timeout, it is breaking the client connection that is why we are getting above mentioned exception.

I increased the timeout value everything got worked!!